# How to map an address of a guest OS to host OS

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, qemu

Given a guest OS address on a virtual machine, how can I map it to host OS and vice versa.

I am running a guest OS (Ubuntu 16.04) using QEMU emulator (version 2.5.0 (Debian 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.26)) on a host Ubuntu 16.04 (linux kernel 4.13.0-41-generic x86_64).

Comment: define "map it to host OS"

Comment: I mean, where within the address space in the host OS. In other word, what is the host virtual address of some guest OS address 0xffffffff00000000. @Lawrence

Comment: Are we talking memory mapping? Are you trying to access the VM Guest memory from the Host OS?

Comment: Yes, memory mapping. Yes I am trying to identify the VM guest memory from the Host. @Lawrence

Comment: There's the `-mem-path` option, which allocates guest RAM from a temporary file, so accessing the file should access guest RAM, but I haven't tested this.